# Get value of static field using reflection in kotlin for generic type

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to get the value of a static field in kotlin for a generic type, but I can't seem to find a good way to do it. I tried reflection and this is what I got so far, but when I run this code in Intellij IDE I get confusing errors and output, so I was not able to debug it properly:

```
open class BaseClass {

    companion object {

        val value = 10
    }
}

class ChildClass: BaseClass() {

    companion object {

        val value = 15
    }
}

inline fun <reified T: BaseClass> getValue(): Int {
    return T::class.java.getDeclaredField("value").get(null) as Int
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(getValue<BaseClass>())
    println(getValue<ChildClass>())
}
```

Is there a better way to do this WITHOUT passing any arguments to `getValue` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I forgot to set `isAccessible` to true. It doesn't matter if the static field is marked as public, `isAccessible` still has to be set to true for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

A frame challenge:

This doesn't seem like a good reason to use reflection.  Reflection's a necessary evil for frameworks, plug-ins, compile-time tools, and similar; but for general coding it's often a code smell.  It can be orders of magnitude slower than non-reflective code (as it can't be optimised in the same way); it's fragile (giving run-time errors for many situations that would otherwise give a compilation error); it's unsafe (as it's easy to overlook all the different run-time errors that it can generate); and it's often more long-winded and harder to read.

It can be tempting if you're coming from a dynamic language, where that sort of approach is common, but in static languages like Kotlin there are usually better alternatives.

And I think there are better approaches here.

First, in the specific case given in the question, when calling the `getValue()` function in the question, you have to provide the class name.  And if you have that, why not just get the value directly??

```
println(BaseClass.value)
println(ChildClass.value)
```

More generally, this sort of requirement more often occurs when you have an *instance* of the base class or some subclass.  (So although you know the type of reference, at compile time you won't necessarily know the type of object, and can't hard-code the classname as above.)

And in that case, a direct property can be a good solution.  You can avoid allocating an extra field in every object, simply by using a custom getter:

```
open class BaseClass {
    open val value get() = 10
}

class ChildClass: BaseClass() {
    override val value get() = 15
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var c = BaseClass()
    println(c.value)
    c = ChildClass()
    println(c.value)
}
```

That gives the *effect* of a static field, but it's actually implemented using a method (the property's getter), which gets overridden in the usual way.

Simpler, clearer, safer, and no reflection needed!

Comment: That's the solution I'd prefer too, but the problem is that I need to have that `value` on a generic type as a static field.

Comment: Hmmm… Could you update the question to show that?  (Remember that Kotlin doesn't have static fields in the way that Java does; companion objects cover roughly similar needs but aren't the same.)